# could not update the fragment argument on re initiating the fragment in viewpager

Tags: android, web-services, android-fragments

I am  re initiating the fragments in view pager on calling the web service, but could not update the argument passing in the fragment. It would remains the same, what is passed at first time.

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
 state = mOverviewData.getState();     
 setupViewPager(mViewPager, isSuccess);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager, boolean isSuccess) 
{

        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        if(isSuccess){
            fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Fragment chartFrag = new OverviewChartFrag();
            Bundle arg = new Bundle();
            arg.putString("state_name",  state);
            arg.putSerializable("total_blocks",  mOverviewData.getTotalBlock());
            arg.putSerializable("block_status_obj",  mOverviewData.getBlockStatusData());
            arg.putParcelableArrayList("mineral_wise_list", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) mineralList);
            chartFrag.setArguments(arg);

            Fragment blocksFrag = new OverviewDataFrag();
            arg = new Bundle();
            arg.putString("state_name",  state);
            arg.putParcelableArrayList("public_data_list", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) mOverviewData.getPublicTableData());
            blocksFrag.setArguments(arg);

            adapter.addFragment(chartFrag, getResources().getString(R.string.chart_tab));
            adapter.addFragment(blocksFrag, getResources().getString(R.string.data_tab));
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Fragment noNetFrag = new ServerErrorFrag();
            adapter.addFragment(noNetFrag, getResources().getString(R.string.error));
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How many fragments you have for your `ViewPager`.

Comment: Viewpager have 2 fragments

Comment: onPostExecution : argument [state] is being updated but it does not passes in the fragment

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call `setupViewPager` inside your `onPostExecute`. Use code below to get a reference of previously added `Fragment`'s and do your work.

```
Adapter adapter = (Adapter) viewPager.getAdapter();
// we don't need but its a fail safe
if (adapter != null) {
    int childCount = adapter.getCount();
    for (int index = 0; index < childCount; index++) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) adapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, index);
        // safe check
        if (fragment != null) {
            // you have a valid reference of your fragment, update its content or GUI
        }
    }
}
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
arguments?.let {
      synchronized(it) {
        arguments?.putString("YOUR_KEY", yourValue)
      }
    }
```